# How Do I Analyze Frequency of Emacs Key Commands?

Tags: emacs

I would like to run an analyzer while using Emacs to identify which key commands I use the most, in order to remap them to (much) easier key combinations. Can anyone recommend one? I doubt I'm the first person to need this. Otherwise, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I think @Xah Lee is the expert on that, but I'm not sure if he still follows stackoverflow on a regular basis.  :)  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/command-frequency.html

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Near the bottom is their [github repo](https://github.com/dacap/keyfreq).

Comment: By the way, stackoverflow seems kind of quiet in the way of Emacs. Do you recommend a better place to ask this type of question?

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions is the best place for general and/or programming Emacs questions; however, stackoverflow (where we are now) is good for a strict programming question where the original poster provides sample code of what almost works, but needs some T.L.C. -- with a statement of what happens and what should happen instead (e.g., expectation) -- include some error messages, etc., to help track down the issues.  The avid Emacs thread readers frequent both forums.  For a discussion with opinions, use:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a melpa package called keyfreq which looks like it would do what your want.

Comment: Same as the github repo mentioned in the comments. Thanks!